# Sometimes my calendar items don't show up

Tags: calendars

I am encoutering a very annoying bug. I hope there is a workaround.

Currently some times during the day or week my calendar items just don't show up and I am not able to add new ones.

What is happening?

Version: 8.10.14234.375
Using Facebook, Google, Microsoft and two Exchange identities